# How to group by a key in json datatype column in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I have the following structure for a JSON column `order_summary` in my `orders` table,

```
//Order 1
{
  "total": 16.895,
  .....
  "products": [
    {
      ...,
      "quantity": 2,
      "variant_id": 98
    },
    {
      ...,
      "quantity": 3,
      "variant_id": 99
    },
  ],
}
//Order 2
{
  "total": 10.895,
  .....
  "products": [
    {
      ...,
      "quantity": 2,
      "variant_id": 98
    },
    {
      ...,
      "quantity": 4,
      "variant_id": 100
    },
  ],
}
```

Now I need to find the total sold quantity for each `variant_id`

I am looking at something like following

```
SELECT sum(order_summary->"$.products[*].quantity") 
FROM orders  
GROUP BY order_summary->"$.products[*].variant_id"
```

But I am just getting zeros. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order_summary->"$.products[*].quantity"` results in an array.

```
mysql> SELECT order_summary->"$.products[*].quantity" from orders;
+-----------------------------------------+
| order_summary->"$.products[*].quantity" |
+-----------------------------------------+
| [2, 3]                                  |
| [2, 4]                                  |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

The sum of which is 0.

```
mysql> select sum("[2,3]");
+--------------+
| sum("[2,3]") |
+--------------+
|            0 |
+--------------+
```

---

To make this work, first you have to convert the JSON into rows using [`json_table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table). Then they can be aggregated like normal columns.

```
select products.*
from orders,
    json_table(
      -- select the JSON column from orders
      orders.order_summary,
      -- filter only the products
      "$.products[*]"
      -- translate them into columns
      columns(
        quantity int path "$.quantity",
        variant_id int path "$.variant_id"
      )
    ) products
;

+----------+------------+
| quantity | variant_id |
+----------+------------+
|        2 |         98 |
|        3 |         99 |
|        2 |         98 |
|        4 |        100 |
+----------+------------+
```

Then we can manipulate the `products` psuedo-table normally.

```
select products.variant_id, sum(products.quantity)
from orders,
    json_table(
      order_summary,
      "$.products[*]"
      columns(
        quantity int path "$.quantity",
        variant_id int path "$.variant_id"
      )
    ) products
group by products.variant_id;

+------------+------------------------+
| variant_id | sum(products.quantity) |
+------------+------------------------+
|         98 |                      4 |
|         99 |                      3 |
|        100 |                      4 |
+------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Wonderful, I hope I could upvote twice, Very detailed indeed. Thank you